# Scrapy:error while obtaining start requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website and my spider is populating start_urls from database first database was in the same directory where is my project. and I was using

```
self.con = lite_db.connect('db.db')
```

to connect to database and it was working. But I needed to change my database location then I tried

```
self.con = lite_db.connect('D:\someFolder\someFolder\db.db')
```

and then my spider started giving this error which means it's not connecting to my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of db:"D:\someFolder\someFolder\db.db" should be escaped,like this:

```
self.con = lite_db.connect('D:\\someFolder\\someFolder\\db.db')
```

or

```
self.con = lite_db.connect(r'D:\someFolder\someFolder\db.db')
```